# exponential of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-exponential

Is there any way to reformulate exponentials of matrix products ($e^{XY}$), where $X,Y\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$? I am interested in how $e^X, e^Y$ relate to $e^{XY}$.
Of particular interest to my research question are:

1. Exponentials of matrix exponents $e^{X^k}$
2. Exponentials of matrix cross-products $e^{X^TX}$

I understand that with scalars $x,y\in\mathbb R$ we have the identity $e^{xy}=(e^x)^y$, and I wonder if an analogous identity is available for matrices.
I am familiar with the rule that, where $Y^{-1}$ exists, we have: $$e^{YXY^{-1}}=Ye^XY^{-1}$$
However I cannot find any further information on more general products.

Comment: I guess you made a typo : shouldn't it be $e^{YXY^{-1}} = Ye^XY^{-1}$ instead ?

Comment: Thanks @abezhiko, corrected now

Comment: It is hard to even extend $e^{xy} = (e^{x})^{y}$ for complex numbers, hence for arbitrary matrices there will also be problems no matter how one defines $(e^X)^Y$.  Should probably restrict yourself onto the set of positive self-adjoint matrices

Comment: I feel that your question is too broad to be answered in a general and satisfying manner. We need more informations about the matrices/operators you shall consider. Are they invertible, (simultaneously) diagonalizable, nilpotent, etc. ? Do they belong to a specific group ? Do they verify a commutation relation ? And what are you going to do next : are you interested in eigenvalues/eigenvectors, determinant, etc. ? You should give us a concrete example in order to clarify what you want to study.